# How to copy selected listview item by copy command in the context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, copy

I've a listview and I want to copy the selected item by selecting the copy command in the context menu. I'm able to create a context menu with the copy command as shown in the image below:

[image]

The problem is when I select a row item and right click it, the context menu wouldn't show and I cannot select the copy command to copy the selected item. The context menu will show when I right click at the empty space in the list view.

[image]

Here's the code:

.xaml

```
<ListView x: Name = "DebugLogLb" BorderBrush = "{x:Null}" SelectionMode = "Extended" MouseRightButtonDown = "DebugLogLb_MouseRightButtonDown">
  <ListViewItem x: Name = "DebugLogItem">
    <ListViewItem.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu x: Name = "CommandMenu">
        <MenuItem Header = "Clear log" Click = "CommandMenuItem_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header = "Copy" Command = "Copy" CommandTarget = "{Binding ElementName=DebugLogItem}"/>       
      </ContextMenu>
    </ListViewItem.ContextMenu>
  </ListViewItem>
</ListView >
```

.xaml.cs:

```
 private void DebugLogLb_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
   ContextMenu contextMenu = this.FindName("CommandMenu") as ContextMenu;
   contextMenu.PlacementTarget = sender as ListViewItem;
   contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
 }

 private void CommandMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
 {
   MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) e.OriginalSource;

   switch (menuItem.Header.ToString())
   {
     case "Clear log":
       DebugLogLb.Items.Clear();
       break;
     default:
       break;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will let you use the ContextMenu with its MenuItems :

```
       <ListView x:Name = "DebugLogLb" BorderBrush = "{x:Null}" SelectionMode = "Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu >
                        <ContextMenu x:Name = "CommandMenu">
                            <MenuItem Header = "Clear log" />
                            <MenuItem Header = "Copy" Command = "Copy" CommandTarget = "{Binding ElementName=DebugLogItem}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView >
```

So, define it inside the ItemTemplate in order to be able to use it when selecting each item.

The items collection is defined in code behind :

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> items { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        items.Add("first item");
        items.Add("second item");
    }
```

Nothing fancy, just for the sake of example.

One more thing, if you still want it available when clicking on the white space, add a ContextMenu on the ListView too:

```
          <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Name = "CommandMenu">
                <MenuItem Header = "Clear log" />
                <MenuItem Header = "Copy" Command = "Copy" CommandTarget = "{Binding ElementName=DebugLogItem}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
```